# Changing form field requirement via ajax

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a selectbox field, that should change the disabled and required states of another field based on the value selected in the selectbox field. The change must be done via ajax.

In my modules form_alter function I have the following code:

```
$form['field_type_app_details']['widget']['#ajax'] = array(
  'callback' => 'ajax_type_callback',
  'event' => 'change'
);
if ($form['field_type_app_details']['widget']["#default_value"][0] === 'First') {
  unset($form['field_version']['#disabled']);
  $form['field_version']['widget'][0]['value']['#required'] = true;
} else {
  $form['field_version']['#disabled'] = 'disabled';
  $form['field_version']['widget'][0]['value']['#required'] = false;
}
```

And the corresponding ajax_type_callback function looks like this:

```
function ajax_type_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['field_type_app_details'];
}
```

What I would expect is, that when I change the value in the selectbox, to i.e. "Second", that the required and disabled states of field_version change accordingly.

What actually happens is, that when I change the value in the selectbox, the ajax request fires correctly, but doesn't change anything of field_version. Additionally, not even the changed value of field_version is saved, when the form gets submitted.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: You should be testing `$form_state->getValue(['field_type_app_details', 'widget', 0, 'value'])` or similar

Comment: @Clive Thanks for the input, but what is the difference between the two variants?

Comment: @Clive I've tried your recommendation, but that just gets me NULL instead of the actual value set in the field, which is "first" at this moment.

Comment: Yeah it was just an example, if you inspect what's in `$form_state->getValues()` you should be able to work out the exact keys you need. The main point is to get that value from the `$form_state`, not from the `$form`, which is the original form build and doesn't contain any user input

Comment: @Clive Thanks for the clarification, I'll try that.

Comment: @Clive If I use $form_state->getValue(['field_type_app_details', 0, 'value']) I get the correct value, but the states of field_version still don't change accordingly.

Comment: Probably because you're returning a different field in the ajax callback, and haven't defined a wrapper to target with the replacement

Comment: Is a wrapper actually necessary every time? I don't want to replace the whole field, just change the required state ...

Comment: If you don't use a wrapper you'll need to construct the AJAX commands yourself in the callback. Perfectly doable, but unnecessary work when you can just replace the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Clive for pointing me in the right direction.

I've managed to accomplish what I want with the following changes to the form_alter function:

```
$form['field_type_app_details']['widget']['#ajax'] = array(
  'callback' => 'ajax_type_callback',
  'event' => 'change',
  'wrapper' => 'version-release'
);
$form['field_version']['#prefix'] = '<div id="version-release">';
$form['field_version']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
$typeValueChangedByUser = $form_state->getValue(['field_type_app_details', 0, 'value']);
$typeToCheck = $typeValueChangedByUser ? $typeValueChangedByUser : $form['field_type_app_details']['widget']['#default_value'][0];
if ($typeToCheck  === 'First') {
  unset($form['field_version']['#disabled']);
  $form['field_version']['widget'][0]['value']['#required'] = true;
} else {
  $form['field_version']['#disabled'] = 'disabled';
  $form['field_version']['widget'][0]['value']['#required'] = false;
}
```

And the following change to the ajax_callback function:

```
function ajax_type_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['field_version'];
}
```